# Ajustar div según ancho de filas de botones

Tags: html5, css, bootstrap

Tengo algunos botones dentro de un div los cuales, al ser muchos, forman nuevas filas hacia abajo, por lo que he hecho un scroll vertical dentro de ese div para tener acceso a todos esos botones.

El problema es que el scroll vertical **no** queda junto a los botones, y eso es lo que necesito, pero se me hace difícil porque el ancho de una fila de botones siempre va a variar según el ancho de la pantalla.

En el snipet, si varían el ancho de su pantalla, pueden ver ese gran espacio variable entre los botones y el scroll, he puesto colores a las divs principales para mejor distinción:

```css
body{
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

#sentlist{
 height: 55px;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

#sli{
 width:auto;
 background-color: #EEAAEE;
}
.otradiv{
 height:50px;
 background-color:orange;
}
button{
  width:50px;
  height:23px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Hi</title>

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inner navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="sentlist" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-11">
        <div id="sli">
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <div class="row otradiv">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Entonces, cualquiera sea el ancho de la pantalla ¿Hay alguna forma de eliminar el espacio entre los botones y el scroll?

**edit**: Ya que no se puede ajustar el ancho del snipet, [aquí](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxMgLz#anon-login) está el codepen.

Answer (score 2):

Si la hay! Agrega a tu CSS:

```
#sentlist { padding-right: 0; }
```

De esa forma se elimina el espacio hacia el interior que tenía antes.

**Edito:**

Con el espacio color violeta el tema es así: este es causa de que no se puede ubicar un botón entre el espacio libre que queda entre dichos botones y el scroll. Para que este no exista no tendría que haber distancia entre los botones y el límite del div que lo contiene (`#sentlist`), por lo que tendrías que modificar el atributo `width` a un valor menor, y utilizar los atributos `@media` que Bootstrap explica muy bien [acá](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) para cada tamaño de pantalla que quieras. En tu caso, quizás, te sea conveniente usar las clases `col-*-` más pequeños.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Casi lo solucionó! el problema es que si te fijas, sigue separándose al cambiar el ancho de la pantalla ;( está fijo al div de la derecha, necesito que se quede fijo a los botones, pero todo el tiempo.

Comment: Hola colega, ahí estuve viendo en codepen lo que me decís, pero cambiando el tamaño de la pantalla en ancho en ningun momento me generó el espacio blanco de nuevo. Bajo que condiciones o medidas ocurre eso que mencionás?

Comment: Acá te dejo el codepen con el cambio aplicado https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMrgqb

Comment: Se elimina el espacio blanco, pero sigue habiendo separación entre los botones y el scroll cuando ajustas el ancho de tu pantalla. Puedes verlos juntos en un momento, pero si encojes la pantalla, se reordenan los botones y aparece un espacio, no blanco, pero sí un espacio entre el scroll y los botones.

Comment: Ahh ahora te entendí perfecto. Ahí edité la respuesta